# How to select except first column in procedure

Tags: sql-server

This is my code but always error

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetThreadDetails(@tid int) 
AS
    SELECT 
        t.uid, fullname, text, dp
    FROM
        threads t, users u 
    WHERE
        tid = @tid and  t.uid = u.uid 

    EXCEPT TOP 1 

    SELECT 
        t.uid, fullname, text, dp
    FROM
        threads t, users u 
    WHERE
        tid = @tid and  t.uid = u.uid 
    ORDER BY
        sno;
```

[There is error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Hiip.png)

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Just remove that column from the select...? Or are you saying everything except the first row? I think this is what you want. Use a CTE and ROW_NUMBER()

Comment: everything except the first row, bro

Comment: That's not the real error message. Click on "view results" to see the actual error message. Also: don't post text as images here. Copy the text.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1):

`EXCEPT TOP 1 SELECT` should be `EXCEPT SELECT TOP 1`.

That said, the set operation is unnecessary here.  Just use the `OFFSET` clause to exclude the first row:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetThreadDetails(@tid int) as
select t.uid, fullname, text, dp
from  threads t , users u 
where tid = @tid and  t.uid = u.uid 
order by sno
OFFSET 1 ROWS;
```